# How to iterate over std::list, while other thread remove elements from it in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, list, thread-safety, pthreads

I have a multi-thread program, where one thread is iterating over a list only reading values and the second is removing some elements from it:

```
std::list<Type> items;

void* Thread1(void*)
{
    while(true)
        for(auto item = items.begin(); item != items.end(); ++item) {
            cout << item << std::endl;
            sleep(1);
        }
}

void* Thread2(void*)
{
    for(auto item = items.begin(); item != items.end(); ++item) {
        if(/*check some condition on item*/) {
            items.erase(item);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't put mutex over whole for loop in `Thread1`, because the list is pretty big and it will cause a big slow-down of the whole program.

Also, `Thread2` will be called multiple times and we can't be sure when it will happen and `Thread1` must look over the list all the time.

Is there a thread-safe way to iterate over a list whose size can change in real-time and not get a segmentation fault, undefined behavior, or potentially skip some elements?

Comment: As well as the potential race condition you have already identified; you also need to take care of [`std::list::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase) _"...References and iterators to the erased elements are invalidated..."_  This will invalidate `item` if the erasing thread and iterating thread are on the same element.

Comment: Short answer:no. `std::list` is not thread safe. Some sort of locking is required.

Comment: a vector with indexes rather than iterators might be safer (though you can still very easily run into undefined behaviour)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so what container would be thead-safe? And if I just need to do lock while modifying list, where should I put mutex? I thought about it for a while and I don't have idea how to safety resolve it with semaphor.

Comment: None of the containers in the C++ library are thread-safe. You must lock the mutex any time any of the containers is used in any way, in a multi-threaded context. If this poses an issue, then some sort of a redesign of the classes and containers will be needed, to implement it in a way that allows for usable thread-safety to be implemented.

Comment: In general, nothing that can be called a "container" is, on its own, thread safe. For example, if you query how many elements are in the container, the result could well become invalid immediately after you get it. Thread safety is something you design into your program, not something you add through libraries. Choosing an appropriate implementation for multi-threading depends strongly on what your application is supposed to do. "Iterate while modifying" is too low level; you have to consider **everything** your program does, not just one thing you happened to notice.

Answer (score 4):

Calling any other member function of the list unsynchronized with a call to `erase` (or any other modifying function) is not guaranteed to be free of a data race and therefore results in undefined behavior. Aside from that there is the obvious issue that the iterator in the other thread may be pointing to exactly the element that is being erased, against which `std::list` does not offer any protection or detection.

If you do not want to take locks, then you'll need to implement your own lock-free list which uses atomic pointers instead to achieve the protection from data races. The standard library does not have any containers of that kind. They all require external locking on modification.